# how to build ionic App built on window and try to build on mac for ios

Tags: ionic-framework

i want to build ionic App built on window now i want to build on mac for ios , when i try to run App on ios device it give errors like 
        CompileC /Users/itr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/On_The_List-amdzpwinuueyorggvkvmgaqbqlkd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/On\ The\ List/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/On\ The\ List.build/Debug-iphoneos/On\ The\ List.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AppDelegate.o On\ The\ List/Classes/AppDelegate.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
        CompileC /Users/itr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/On_The_List-amdzpwinuueyorggvkvmgaqbqlkd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/On\ The\ List/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/On\ The\ List.build/Debug-iphoneos/On\ The\ List.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MainViewController.o On\ The\ List/Classes/MainViewController.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    (2 failures)

```
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/itr/Desktop/onthelist-n/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,On The List.xcworkspace,-scheme,On The List,-configuration,Debug,-destination,generic/platform=iOS,-archivePath,On The List.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/itr/Desktop/onthelist-n/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/itr/Desktop/onthelist-n/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

Comment: can anyone help me in that

Comment: Try removing and re-adding the latest platform.

Comment: Already tried it not working

Comment: Build it with xcode, Open plaltforms/ios/{PROJECT}.xcodeproj with xcode.

Comment: Also tried not working

Comment: Try `ionic cordova build ios`, then open plaltforms/ios/{PROJECT}.xcodeproj. And follow the steps in https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/

Comment: i tried this too

Comment: Try building with ionic package. Give it a shot and let me know if it works.

Comment: Not working for me